# Show this custom text in one specific category

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

How to alter this custom text, so it will only be shown in one specific category, let's say: ONLY in category: tables?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'show_meer_varianten_loop', 100 );
function show_meer_varianten_loop() { ?>
    <div class="custom-label-variable">✓ Meer varianten</div>
    <?php
}
```

in css:

```php
.products .product:not(.product-type-variable) .custom-label-variable {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using WooCommerce so check your body classes.
There should be some class that references that category like *category_tables* or *term-01*.

You can manage your CSS like this:

```
body:not(.category_tables) .products .product:not(.product-type-variable) .custom-label-variable {
    display: none;
}
```

It's not the best option, but it's a quick and effective solution for those who don't know how to work with WP Functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..I think it works ..

```
add_action( 
'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 
'show_meer_varianten_loop', 100 );
function show_meer_varianten_loop() 
{ 
global $product;       
if ( has_term( 'tables', 
'product_cat', $product->ID ) ) { ?>
 <div class="custom-label- 
  variable">✓ Meer varianten</div>
  <?php
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work right.
Every product in that categorie has now <div class="custom-label- 
  variable">✓ Meer varianten</div>. Single and variable products

Comment: Isn't it what u want? U said products in tables category..what exactly u want?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from @helgatheviking:

The working one is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'show_meer_varianten_loop', 100 );
function show_meer_varianten_loop() {
global $product;
if ( $product && has_term( 'tables', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) { ?>
<div class="custom-label-variable">✓ Meer varianten</div>
<?php
}
}
```